# how to solve error "500, Internal Server error" while creating new credential in Db2-oc in IBM cloud?

Tags: database, ibm-cloud

[This is the error which I am getting on creating new credential in service credential of Db2-oc in IBM cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ghmz.png)

Comment: You did not say which service plan of Db2 on Cloud, which region, and how you tried to create the credentials. Without that information, your question cannot be answered. Please do not post links to images, but embed them - better type / post the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the only way I got to solve the error was by deleting the DB2 resource from my IBM session and adding it again.

Once I did that, it allowed me to create new credentials.

Regards